# Reduce CPU utilization while constant pinging to API and saving data in hosted services

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, cpu-usage

I have this function in hosted service which grabs the data from API every second and process the data and save it into the database.

I have similar 3 more hosted services which run at the same time. Because of function `GetBuilds()` , the CPU utilization is always high, I'm sure because of the `foreach` loops in function and services but without that, it's hard to iterate over data.

CPU utilization increases significantly after calling `GetBuilds()`, is there a way to optimize this function?

```
public async Task GetBuilds() {
    var data = new List<GetBuildTempClass>();
    var guids = new List<Guid>();

    using (var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope()) {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
            string commandText = @"SELECT 
                                      a.name as AppName,
                                      a.app_guid as AppGuid
                                   FROM
                                     apps as a
                                   INNER JOIN
                                     spaces as s ON a.space_guid = s.space_guid
                                   INNER JOIN
                                     organizations as o ON s.org_guid = o.org_guid
                                   WHERE
                                     s.name != 'system' and o.name != 'system' and a.foundation = 2 and a.deleted_at IS NULL";
            try {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection);
                await connection.OpenAsync();
                using (DbDataReader reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync()) {
                    while (await reader.ReadAsync()) {
                        var sqlresult = new GetBuildTempClass {
                            AppName = reader["AppName"].ToString(),
                            AppGuid = reader.GetGuid(reader.GetOrdinal("AppGuid"))
                        };

                        data.Add(sqlresult);
                    }
                }
            } finally {
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }

    using (var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope()) {
        var _DBcontext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<PCFStatusContexts>();
        foreach (var app in data) {
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "apps/" + app.AppGuid + "/builds?per_page=200&order_by=updated_at");
            var response = await _client_SB.SendAsync(request);
            var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            BuildsClass.BuildsRootObject model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BuildsClass.BuildsRootObject>(json);

            foreach (var item in model.resources) {
                var x = _DBcontext.Builds.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Guid == Guid.Parse(item.guid));
                if (x == null) {
                    _DBcontext.Builds.Add(new Builds {
                        Guid = Guid.Parse(item.guid),
                        State = item.state,
                        CreatedAt = item.created_at,
                        UpdatedAt = item.updated_at,
                        Error = item.error,
                        CreatedByGuid = Guid.Parse(item.created_by.guid),
                        CreatedByName = item.created_by.name,
                        CreatedByEmail = item.created_by.email,
                        AppGuid = app.AppGuid,
                        AppName = app.AppName,
                        Foundation = 2,
                        Timestamp = DateTime.Now
                    });
                } else if (x.UpdatedAt != item.updated_at) {
                    x.State = item.state;
                    x.UpdatedAt = item.updated_at;
                    x.Timestamp = DateTime.Now;
                }

                guids.Add(Guid.Parse(item.guid));
            }
        }

        var apps = _DBcontext.Builds.Where(o => guids.Contains(o.Guid) == false && o.Foundation == 2 && o.DeletedAt == null);
        foreach (var app_item in apps) {
            app_item.DeletedAt = DateTime.Now;
        }

        await _DBcontext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: How many new builds would you typically have in a cycle?

Comment: around 50-60 and they get updated every second so I need its updated state

Comment: I'd be tempted to put some stopwatches around some parts of this and figure out what is taking so much processing power.  My guess is the slow part is `foreach (var app in data)`.  But I'm not sure if it's the 50-60 API calls you make inside that loop? Or if it's the database inserts.

Comment: Yeah, you are right about `foreach (var app in data)` thats the root cause of the problem and problem is calling and processing the data. Saving happens in last and thats only one time.

Comment: each  `foreach (var app in data) {` could be done a new thread(multi threaded). but yes first fix `foreach (var item in model.resources) {` the db fetch inside here is going to kill your performance.... make one that fetchs all then holds in mem then loop.

Comment: Can you not just make the one call with all of your builds using a Table valued parameter?

Comment: You can't improve code that's too big to understand. Break this method into smaller ones that do *one* thing. Polling, downloading, storing. Once you do that you'll be able to execute each one separately, possibly *batch* records before inserting them in the database with SqlBulkCopy. Why all those scopes too, and mixing EF Core with plain ADO.NET ? This code doesn't deal entities, it just inserts records

Comment: @SeanT I cant make only one call the way API endpoint is weird I have to make call the way I did in my code.

Comment: @Sam Sorry I'm not referring to the api - I'm referring to `var item in model.resources` loop. You can reduce that to 1 call to the database using a stored procedure and TVP. That will improve speed by an order of magnitude

Comment: @SeanT I'm not really familiar with it I'm very new to .net but I will look into it now. Thank you for the input

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Sure makes sense for separating all in smaller I will try this but without scopes the data retrieval get slow. I tried making all this in once scope or without scope.

Comment: @Sam scopes don't affect queries *at all*. The way you use them though create a new DbContext instance in each case. You should have created that DbContext explicitly, inside a using block, *in a separate function*. You gain nothing by using scopes like this. The code is still performing inserts in a very slow way. There's no reason to use EF Core here, there are no entities

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos so should I just eliminate whole EF and use plain simple SQL?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos is it possible for you to show me your approach in code?

Answer (score 1):

see below pseudo-code

```
//...omitted for readability
var resourceGuids = model.resources.Select(x=>x.guid).ToList();
var existingBuilds = _DBcontext.Builds.Where(x => resourceGuids.Contains(x.Guid).ToList();

foreach (var item in model.resources) {
    var x = existingBuilds.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Guid == Guid.Parse(item.guid));

//...omitted for readability
```

then for the main loop convert to multithreaded.

**update**

further as this is async your FirstOrDefault should be FirstOrDefaultAsync
to incorp with the changes above it would be

```
 var existingBuilds = await _DBcontext.Builds.Where(x => guids.Contains(x.Guid).ToListAsync();
```

**update**

Personaly i would also do all the http stuff and then process the data..

```
List<BuildsClass.BuildsRootObject> httpResp = new List<BuildsClass.BuildsRootObject>();
//this could be change to be multi threaded.. 
//as the wait time on response here would be the longest so do in parallel
foreach (var item in data) { 
{
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "apps/" + item.AppGuid + "/builds?per_page=200&order_by=updated_at");
    var response = await _client_SB.SendAsync(request);
    var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    BuildsClass.BuildsRootObject model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BuildsClass.BuildsRootObject>(json);
    if(model !=null)
    {
        httpResp.Add(model)
    }
}

  using (var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope()) {

        var _DBcontext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<PCFStatusContexts>();

        foreach(var item in httpResp)
        {
            //fetch all the data
            var resourceGuids = item.resources.Select(x=>x.guid).ToList();
            var existingBuilds = await _DBcontext.Builds.Where(x => guids.Contains(x.Guid).ToListAsync();

            foreach(var item2 in item.resources)
            {
                ...ommited for readability
            }

        }

        ...ommited for readability
```

Comment: is it possible for you to give a complete example instead of pieces? I'm new to .net it will help understand better.

Comment: FYI, you're missing the end parenthesis on your `Where`s (I know, it's pseudo code, but...). Also, consider whether you need `.ToList()` or `.ToListAsync()`. Finally, the **update**s make it hard to understand your answer. Consider [edit]ing your answer to make it one cohesive whole rather than three separate answers...